# similarity between strings

Tags: algorithms, string-metrics

I have found this tool:

https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/string_similarity/

and it says that is based on the article:

"An O(ND) Difference Algorithm and its Variations"

available on: http://www.xmailserver.org/diff2.pdf

I have read the article, but I have some doubts about how they programmed that tool, for example the authors said that it is based on the C library GNU diff and analyze.c; maybe it refers to this:

https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/

and this: https://github.com/masukomi/dwdiff-annotated/blob/master/src/diff/analyze.c

The problem that I have is how to understand the relation of that software tool with the article. For what I read it shows an algorithm for finding the LCS (longest common subsequence) between a pair of strings, so they use a modification of the dynamic programming algorithm used for solving this problem. The modification is the use of the shortest path algorithm to find the LCS that has the minimum number of modifications.

At this point, how they use that theory to find the percentage of similarity between a couple of strings. I know that, for example, the Leveshestein distance can use dynamic programming for knowing the number of edits to transform one string to another; which is something quite similar that they do in the article. Nevertheless, what is the relationship between the LCS and string similarity?

Also they use a threshold of 0.4 in the software took that I do not know for what it is. Anyway, where did I get lost? Any help, please.

Comment: The algorithm used by GNU difftools is indeed the Myers algorithm with a few heuristics to avoid pathological behaviour when $D$ and $N$ are of similar order. However, your tools page doesn't explain how it measures "similarity", and like you, we have nothing to go on. If I had to come up with a quick and dirty LCSS-based measure of similarity, I'd use something like Jaccard similarity: if $M$ is the size of one string, $N$ is the size of the other string and $L$ is the size of the LCSS, then similarity is $\frac{L}{M+N-L}$.

Comment: thank you very much for your comment @Pseudonym, I suppose that the LCSS is used to see how similar are each string sequence based on how many edits should be done in each string to match the LCSS. If I am wrong, could you please explain it a little bit more?

Comment: Pretty much. The LCSS is a measure of how much two strings have in common. To get a normalised similarity measure, you need to scale that, somehow, by the length of the strings.

Comment: We expect references to fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible. Please take some time to improve your post in this regard. We have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1201/).

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!